# jqgrid filterToolbar not working

Tags: jqgrid

Well i am banging my head against the wall with this one because i have used jqgrid in many apps and similar code is working in every other case but this!
Here is the code...

```
var pfct = $("#pfc_table");
pfct.jqGrid({
        url: 'costs',
        datatype: 'json',
        'postData': JSON.stringify(getConds()),
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['Id','Name','Formula','Conditions'],
        colModel :[
          {name:'id', index:'id', width:40, search:true},
          {name:'name', index:'name', width:130, search:true},
          {
              name:'formula', index:'formula',width:310, search:true,
              formatter : function(value, options, rData){
                  return value.substring(value.indexOf('=')+1);
              }
          },
          {name:'conditionstr', index:'conditionstr', width:160,search:true}
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems:false,
            root: function (r) { return r.data.rows; },
            page: function (r) { return r.data.currpage; },
            total: function (r) { return r.data.totalpages; },
            records: function (r) { return r.data.totalrecords; }
        },
        gridComplete: function() {
        },
        gridview: true,
        height: 'auto',
        autowidth: true,
        pager: '#pfc_pager',
        rowNum:25,
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        multiselect: false,
        pagination: true
});
pfct.navGrid('#pfc_pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false});
pfct.jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter: false});
```

The json data i am sending have a few extra properties that are not defined in the colmodel but this has never been a problem in the past. Local sorting and paging works fine, but filtering does not!
For the record this is what the data looks like:

```
{"data":{"totalpages":1,"currpage":1,"totalrecords":10,"rows":[{"name":"Test","id":18195,"level":0,"currency":"EUR","default":true,"formula":"f_18195()=110","ownerId":1,"categoryName":"Test cat","parentId":0,"rebate":0,"portDues":true,"modified":1310036286000,"conditionstr":"Condition 1, Condition 2"}],"userdata":null},"status":true,"responseError":null}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the filtering in the 'name' column not work or you have problem with the filtering in all columns? What do `getConds` function? Could you post the code of `getConds` or try whether you have problem with the filtering if you remove `'postData': JSON.stringify(getConds())`?

Comment: The filtering does not work on any column. getConds() creates a simple javascript object that has an array of integers and works fine (the server parses this and returns the matching results). I will try removing this however i doubt it has anything to do with it. Something else i noticed is that if i try to premeptively perform a sort on a column (default sort) it does not work but it works afterwards (by clicking on that column). Also, if i type something on any of the filter text boxes the default sort is applied but nothing gets filtered. I guess i ll use the source of jqgrid and debug

Comment: Hmm, i tried with local data and it now works as it should be. There is no difference in the actual data and the only changes in the table definition have to do with the data being now local. Wierd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [original grid](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/nvrs.htm) has one problem. You use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) for the 'formula' column:

```
formatter : function(value, options, rData){
    return value.substring(value.indexOf('=')+1);
}
```

so the data `"f_18195()=110"` will be displayed as `"100"`. The way works good in case of `datatype: 'json'` *without* `loadonce: true`, but works wrong in case of `loadonce: true`. The problem is that the data saved locally for the `formula` column will be `"f_18195()=110"` and not `"100"`. So during filtering of the data one have to type "f" or "f_18195()=1" instead of "1" to filter the data:

[image]

You can fix the problem if you would use `jsonmap` as function:

```
jsonmap: function (obj) {
    var f = obj.formula;
    return f.substring(f.indexOf('=')+1);
}
```

instead of usage of usage of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) for the 'formula' column. In the case the value "100" will be saved locally and the filtering of data works as expected:

[image]

See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/nvrs1.htm).